# Bootstrap inline responsive nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Subj. How? (like multilevel menu in screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Look under `Responsive Navbar`

Comment: need the inline menu, without .btn-navbar